# Restart the timer in select() of socket programming

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I want to use select() to receive update from other server and also send out periodic messages. Consider the following set up:

> while(1){
>   select(... timeout = 5 seconds);
>   // some other code}

If I receive update at **t = 2** seconds, then **select()** will return and corresponding statement will be executed. When the next loop begins, timeout will be set to 5 seconds again. However, it should be **5 - 2 = 3** seconds. Is there a way to update the timer with the right time?

I thought about to manually start a timer righr before select(), however this timer might not be synchronous with the one used in **select()**. And will cause other potential problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`select` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select):

> On Linux, `select()` modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not slept; most other implementations do not do this. (POSIX.1-2001 permits either behaviour.)

So, you just simply reuse the `timeout` variable. You only reset its value when you really time-out.

As the warning suggests, relying on this behavior makes for a porting problem, so if you rely on this behavior, make sure you document it so that the right thing is done when porting the code.

Comment: I am coding on windows machine, but the program will be tested on Linux. So is it better to re-set timeout everytime, so that porting problem could be avoided?

Comment: Yes, you can do that (as @MichalRus suggested). Or, you can create a separate thread to do the periodic processing. That thread can just sleep for 5 seconds, then do something, in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember `time()` in a variable before you call `select()`, get another `time()` when `select()` returns and... in the next `while(1)` iteration use not `5`, but `5 - difference_between_times` for timeout value.

Perhaps you'd want to use `new_timeout = 5 - difference_between_times % 5`, so that if *your* operation after `select` returns takes longer than 5 seconds... you still set the `timeout` in 5 sec interval.

You probably should use not seconds, but some more granular time unit. And think whether above is the behaviour you really want (with modulo). Maybe when `difference_between_times > 5`, you should wait just for 5 sec. Do as you wish, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

When your app gets a little more complicated, you may have multiple timers with different timeout intervals.  We do.  Here is how we handle it.

Each timer has a timer object with a time_t of when the timer expires.  We store all the timers in a heap data structure, so the soonest timer to expire is at the root of the heap. Before doing a select() we fetch the root of the heap, and subtract the current time from the timer's expiration time and use that delta as the timeout to the select() call.

```
Timer * t = heap->Root();
time_t now = time(0);
timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = t->when - now;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
select( ... & tv );
```